# logging with flexunit

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flexunit

I am using FlexUnit4 with FlashBuilder4.  A lot of the classes that I'm unit testing make use of the [Flash Logger](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/logging/ILogger.html).

In the main app, we use [TraceTarget](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/logging/targets/TraceTarget.html) so that the logging shows up in the trace window, which greatly aids in debugging:

```
<!-- route logging to the trace window -->
<mx:TraceTarget includeTime="true"/>
```

I'd like to do the same thing for the unit test runner that FlashBuilder generates (FlexUnitApplication.mxml), but I'm not sure how to go about it.  I could, of course, add TraceTarget to FlexUnitApplication.mxml, but as the warning at the top of the file says,

```
<!-- This is an auto generated file and is not intended for modification. -->
```

modifying it probably isn't a good idea.

My question is: how do I get logging-to-trace to work with FlashBuilder and FlexUnit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a cue from the method mentioned in [this article](http://patrickmowrer.com/2010/03/09/using-custom-runners-flash-builder-4s-built-flexunit4-support) and created a UnitTestRunner.mxml that inherits from FlexUnitApplication:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<local:FlexUnitApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                             xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                             xmlns:local="*"                             
                             minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- send log messages to trace window -->
        <s:TraceTarget includeTime="true"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
</local:FlexUnitApplication>
```

and then set the Flash Builder settings to run UnitTestRunner instead of FlexUnitApplication (Preferences->Flash Builder->FlexUnit->Custom Application Name).